# SQL Count number of records that appear more than once a month and aggregate by month

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datepart

I am going through a ton of records and want to count the number of times an ID is updated more than once a month.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Frequency, MONTH(Date) AS MM, YEAR(Date) AS YYYY, Id 
FROM data
WHERE -- [some filtering] 
    AND Date <=  -- end date 
    AND Date >=  -- start date 
GROUP BY Date, Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY MM DESC
```

Now what happens there is that I am only finding the number of Id's that are updated more than once per day. What I want to do is to group the ID's by month.

I have tried using the column MM in my GROUP BY but then I get error codes stating that these are invalid column selections.

I tried using the following GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date), Id
```

All I get is continuous 8120 errors and I cannot figure out how I should put this together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Slight detour...but something you probably need to read before you continue splattering NOLOCK everywhere. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Also, when getting error messages it is helpful to provide the error message instead of just the number as most people don't have all the numbers memorized.

Comment: Appreciate the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

First let's fix your query so it does proper aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Frequency, MONTH(Date) AS MM, YEAR(Date) AS YYYY, Id 
FROM data with(NOLOCK)
WHERE -- [some filtering] 
GROUP BY MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date), Id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY YYYY, MM DESC
```

This gives you a list of `Id`s that were updated more than once each month.

Now, if you want to know how many `Id`s were updated more than once each month, you can add another level of aggregation:

```
SELECT MM, YYY, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Frequency, MONTH(Date) AS MM, YEAR(Date) AS YYYY, Id 
    FROM data with(NOLOCK)
    WHERE -- [some filtering] 
    GROUP BY MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date), Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) x
ORDER BY YYYY, MM DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, we are more interested in which IDs and how many times they were updated that month.

Comment: @Viss: ok; the first query answers that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I dunno if I was just burnt out / tired.